# Almost continuity implies measurability?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

Trying to prove the continuity of $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ $(n>1)$ I got the following property of $ f $:

for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n $ and $(x_k)$ such that $x_k \rightarrow x$ the adhesion values ​​of $\{f(x_k)\}_k$ always tend to $f(x)$ i.e. if there $(x_{k_i})_i$ such that $f(x_{k_i})\rightarrow y$ then $y=f(x)$.

I wonder if $ f $ is measurable borel.

any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a compact set $K$, and let $S = f^{-1}(K)$.  Suppose a sequence $s_n$  of members of $S$ has a limit $x$.  Then $f(s_n)$ is a sequence in $K$, so some subsequence has a limit: $f(s_{n_j}) \to y \in K$.  But then by your condition
$y = f(x)$, and so $x \in S$.  Thus the inverse images of compact sets are closed.  Now since any open set in ${\mathbb R}^n$ is a countable union of 
compact sets, the inverse image of an open set is Borel (in fact is an $F_\sigma$), and  $f$ is Borel measurable.